# How to return multiple conditions?

Tags: java

What should be my return at the end of my for loop? I'm trying to display the added results of all three parties numDemocrat, numRepulican and numIndepent by
calculating and then printing the number of democrats (party is "D"),
republicans (party is "R"), and independents (party is anything else).
I'm currently looping over the MemberOfCongress ArrayList returned by parseMembersOfCongress and counting up how many of each party type there are.
Also in my loop I need to check which party the current member belongs to and increment the proper variable. After the loop completes I then print the totals.

```
public void printPartyBreakdownInSenate() 
    {

    CongressDataFetcher.fetchSenateData(congressNum);
    } 

    {
    ArrayList<MemberOfCongress> parseMembersOfCongress; String jsonString;

    }

    {
     System.out.println("Number of Members of the Senate of the " + "&congressNum=" + "?chamber=");
    }

    public String[]  
    {
         int numDemocrats = 0;
         int numRepblican = 0;
         int numIndepent = 0;


        ArrayList<MemberOfCongress> members;
        for (MemberOfCongress memberParty : members) {

             if (memberParty.getParty() == "D" ) {
                 numDemocrats++;
             }
             else if (memberParty.getParty() == "R" ){
                       numRepblican++;
                 }
                 else if (memberParty.getParty() == "null"){
                           numIndepent++;
                 }
         }



        return ???;

}
```

Comment: i would prefer `map`.

Comment: This code wouldn't even compile.

Comment: Try to run your code & remove all the compilation errors first

Answer (score 0):

Firstly i'm 99% positive you cannot return multiple values, unless your return either an array, an array list or a map.

But what you could do as a work around is one of the following.

1). Return a String array of party members.

2). Return a 2D array mapping name to age or something similar.

3). Return a hashmap of the data with a custom class of information mapped to a name.

4). Use getters to get different pieces of the data at time or all at once.

Comment: hmm option 1.) and 4.) seem more viable.

Comment: I would suggest option number 4, just a better way of doing things.

Comment: option 5.) create a class which can hold the desired data and return an obect of this class.

Answer (score 0):

Java (like the majority of programmming languages) allows only a single return value from a method. There are lots of good reasons for this.

If you need to return multiple values then you will need a separate class for which your method can return a reference to an instance.

For example, in your case:

```
public enum Party {
    REPUBLICAN, DEMOCRAT, OTHER;
}

public Map<Party, Integer> senatorsByParty(List<MemberOfCongress> senators) {
    return senators.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MemberOfCongress::getParty, Collectors.counting()));
}
```

Apologies if you are not aware of the Java 8 syntax here. The stream functions are really just saying 'take all the senators, group them by party and then count them'. The key point is that you are returning a map from parties to integers representing the count of senators.